# How can I add a local copy of a globally installed NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Is there a way to make NPM install my global packages to a project?

I like the idea of installing NPM packages globally as it will allow me to copy the package to my local project if I don't have any network. What I did was this:

```
> npm install -g parcel react react-dom
```

This installed the packages `parcel`, `react` and `react-dom` to a global `node_modules` folder. The issue that I have is that if I want to make a new project, and I run the following:

```
> npm install -D parcel
> npm install react react-dom
```

Then NPM downloads packages from the online repository. Is there a way to make NPM copy the files from my global `node_modules` folder? I tried searching for this, but all I managed to find is pages about `npm install -g <pkg>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same modules of your project to others you need to install these modules globally with the command `npm install -g <pkg>`

If you want to install the same version of the module you are using in other project just use the command `npm install <pkg>@<version>`

If you want to have the exacts same modules packages you can copy and paste the node_modules's folder of your previous project to the current (pay attention to do this because it may cause some vulnerability on your newest project)